# How do I make my simple website mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple webpage with just a full size image background. What do I do to make it mobile friendly? The css looks like this:

```
html{
  background: url(images/grindif1.jpg) 50% no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
  min-height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

[image: On a computer, it looks like this (as i want).]

[image: And on the phone, it looks like this]

Comment: What are you envisioning in particular?

Comment: I do not see anything mobile unfriendly here. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: That looks normal! what is not like you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, like Dany Code said don't put a background image on "html" tag but on the body.

If you don't like the result of background-size:cover; at a certain breakpoints of the viewport size your can always make different css rules for those specific media queries.

If you want the image on phones, to appear a certain wY different then they appear on desktop, you can use the " @media screen and ( max-width: 480px) { your css code here for the iphone specific } "

Answer (score 1):

Ok you looking for somthing like this?

And  by the way try to put nothing on the `html` in your CSS if then use the `body` and put `margin:0px;`

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600) 50% no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: green;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is very unclear but since you asked for mobile compatibility I would suggest [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Bootstrap has classes for mobile & desktop sites and its easy to use. It follows the grid system. And has different classes to support different viewports:

- col-xs- ~ Extra small devices
- col-sm- ~ Small devices
- col-md- ~ Medium devices
- col-lg- ~ Large devices